# IntelliJ IDEA: inject language with String.format()

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an SQL query which unfortunately cannot be written as a *prepared statement* because it has variable column names. Because of this, I have to build my SQL using String formatting.

The language (SQL dialect) I'm using is PostgreSQL, but because I have `String.format()` in my queries, IntelliJ complains about syntax errors in my code.

```java
public class Example {
    public String getUniqueFeatureCountSqlQuery(String feature, Long sourceUserId) {
        //language=PostgreSQL
        return String.format("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT targetUserId), %s FROM userComments GROUP BY %s WHERE userId = %d",
            feature, feature, sourceUserId);
    }
}
```

[image]

How do I make IntelliJ recognize this string properly? It should know that it is PostgreSQL which is first formatted by `String.format()`.

Comment: What do you mean by variable column names?  The names look hard-coded to me.  Wouldn't this leave you vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My mistake. I edited my question so it should be clearer now. Assume "feature" has already been sanitized.

Comment: It seems to be related to this fixed bug but I couldn't get it to work. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139305

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @WillHumphreys I found a solution via [youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139305).

You have to go the the User Parameters settings under Tools -> Database -> User Parameters, or use the find action command.

[image]

Then make these changes.

[image]

You may also have to use the argument index string format notation (`String.format("SELECT %1s ...", ...)`) for the parameters to be distinguishable when attempting to alt-enter run the query in the console.